# Let Autotools compile each header to ensure stand-alone property

Tags: c++, autotools

I have a C++ codebase which uses templates a lot and therefore is header-only for the most part. The only time that something gets compiled is for the test cases. The build system used is GNU Autotools.

During work on the codebase I noticed that headers are rarely stand-alone. Headers only work if they are included in the right order and after the ones they (implicitly) depend on. When I add a header myself, I try to make it stand-alone and include the needed bits. Then I see that those bits were not standalone either.

Compiling the unit tests gives me errors, but the test is not as strong as I would like. I think I want to call `g++ -c` on each header file. If they are formed correctly, they should all compile, right?

How could I tell GNU Autotools in a maintainable way that it should compile each header into an object file in order to see whether dependencies are correctly specified via `#include`?

Comment: Every header should be included within a compilation unit to be checked during compilation. Ever templae should be instantiated. Include order should not matter. Fix your headers.

Comment: @knivil: That is exactly what I am trying to do. However, there is just a single huge compilation unit. Therefore I can only test if it is correct globally. There are headers `A.h`, `B.h`, and `C.h`, but there *is no* `A.cc`. There is only *one* `main.cc` where everything gets included in a particular ordering. I *could* write `A.cc` with `#include "A.h"` as the sole contents, but I rather think it should be possible to just run `g++ -c -o A.o A.h` to check the header without actually having to create the file `A.cc`. And that is what I am asking about.

Comment: I would write a shell script that parses the directory, generates cc-files and tries to compile.

Comment: @MartinUeding If some headers depend on others, why don't you include tthem in the dependend header directly, instead of leaving getting that right for the user  of your library?

Comment: For GCC you need to specify `-x c++` in order to compile a header file like a source file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I am new to this codebase, and I want to fix the situation. For that, I need a bit better tooling than just having one huge compilation unit.

Comment: @Martin I still don't get your concern. Do you want to find out the dependencies of these headers, to fix them in the way I proposed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, I need to find the dependencies. And currently it is rather hard to do. With smaller compilation units, I will get more helpful error messages.

Comment: _@Martin_ Well, then I'd follow @krivil's advice and write a small shell script to generate the compilation units for the tests. You won't catch any errors that appear with template instantiations though.